# FIWARE - Orion Context Broker

Tags: fiware-orion

I am developing an application to share the sets of data that are read by sensors in FIWARE platform. Can somebody help me how to carry out this work using Orion Context Broker?

Comment: My client has set up the sensors to read the data and the data is successfully displayed in their website. They are asking me to develop an applications on FIWARE so that they can share the data to other people using the FIWARE technology.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation on Orion Context Broker is available here: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion

Answer (score 0):

Orion Context Broker contains the latest snapshot of the sensor values, it's not intended for publication of static datasets. But you can connect Orion to CKAN (especially if you are confortable with Open Data) as explained at:

https://www.fiware.org/devguides/publishing-open-data-in-fiware/how-to-publish-context-information-as-open-data-in-ckan/

If you don't want to deal with CKAN, you should consider taking a look at IoT-STH, a GE candidate for "Short Term Historic":

https://github.com/telefonicaid/IoT-STH